# Two symmetric matrices with same characteristic polynomial are congruent.

Tags: matrices, symmetric-matrices, congruence-relations

> Two symmetric matrices with same characteristic polynomial are congruent.

I know that the above statement is false, But I can't understand why it's false.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Does congruent mean equal or similar?

Comment: Two matrices $A$ and $B$ are congruent if there exists an invertible matrix $Q$ such that $A=Q^TBQ. $

Comment: And are you working over an arbitrary field?

Comment: I am working in the field of reals.

Comment: Real symmetric matrices are diagonalizable, which means the statement is true. Complex matrices on another hand are a different story....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint** If $A,B$ are symmetric and real, they are diagonalizable. Moreover, since they have the same characteristic polynomial, they can be diagonalized to the same diagonal matrix.

Use this to prove they are congruent.

**Note:** For complex, the canonical example of a non-diagonalizable matrix is
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1& i \\-i &-1
\end{bmatrix}   $$

This matrix has both eigenvalues equal to $0$, which means is not diagonalizable, and hence not congruent with its diagonal.

Comment: Can you provide an example where this isn't true?

Comment: @user333900 Done. For complex, the right objects are hermitian matrices, not symmetric.